# Large temporary database to sanitize data in Python

Tags: python, xml, sanitization

I have a large amount of data that I am pulling from an xml file that all needs to be validated against each other (in excess of 500,000 records). It is location data, so it has information such as: county, street prefix, street suffix, street name, starting house number, ending number. There are duplicates, house number overlaps, etc. and I need to report on all this data (such as where there are issues). Also, there is no ordering of the data within the xml file, so each record needs to be matched up against all others.

Right now I'm creating a dictionary of the location based on the street name info, and then storing a list of the house number starting and ending locations. After all this is done, I'm iterating through the massive data structure that was created to find duplicates and overlaps within each list. I am running into problems with the size of the data structure and how many errors are coming up.

One solution that was suggested to me was to create a temporary SQLite DB to hold all data as it is read from the file, then run through the DB to find all issues with the data, report them out, and then destroy the DB. Is there a better/more efficient way to do this? And any suggestions on a better way to approach this problem?

As an fyi, the xml file I'm reading in is over 500MB (stores other data than just this street information, although that is the bulk of it), but the processing of the file is not where I'm running into problems, it's only when processing the data obtained from the file.

EDIT: I could go into more detail, but the poster who mentioned that there was plenty of room in memory for the data was actually correct, although in one case I did have to run this against 3.5 million records, in that instance I did need to create a temporary database.

Comment: consider using the Python standard library bsddb package. It presents a dictionary interface but is backed by either a hash table or a b-tree on disk.

Comment: That has been deprecated since 2.6 http://docs.python.org/library/bsddb.html

Comment: OK, use http://www.jcea.es/programacion/pybsddb.htm and the bsddb3 module ... same idea, slightly different name.

Comment: It is not apparent what your problem really is, nor why transcribing your data from XML to a DB would solve it. You say "duplicates, house number overlaps, etc": Is "Fubar St" a duplicate of "Foughbarre Street"? "Rue de Foughbarre"? Do house numbers (2,100) overlap with (1,99)? What is "etc"? You say "problems with the size of the data structure and how many errors" -- Can you hold your data structure in memory or not? How much memory is grabbed by merely parsing your big XML file without building that dictionary? What constitutes an "error"? Why is the volume of errors a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

500,000 is not a large number, why can't you just go thru all record create a dict out of relevant entries and check whatever you need to check e.g.

```
import random
import time

class Data(object):
    ID = 0
    def __init__(self, data):
        Data.ID+=1
        self.id =Data.ID
        self.data = data
        self.duplicates = None

def fill_data(N):
    data_list = []
    # create alist of random data
    sample = list("anuraguniyal")
    for i in range(N):
        random.shuffle(sample)
        data_list.append(Data("".join(sample)))
    return data_list

def find_duplicate(data_list):
    data_map = {}
    for data in data_list:
        if data.data in data_map:
            data_map[data.data].append(data)
        else:
            data_map[data.data] = [data]

        data.duplicates = data_map[data.data]

st = time.time()
data_list = fill_data(500000)
print "fill_data time:", time.time()-st
st = time.time()
find_duplicate(data_list)
print "find_duplicate time:", time.time()-st

total_duplicates = 0
max_duplicates = 0
for data in data_list:
    total_duplicates += (len(data.duplicates) - 1)
    max_duplicates = max(len(data.duplicates),max_duplicates)
print "total_duplicates count:",total_duplicates
print "max_duplicates count:",max_duplicates
```

output:

```
fill_data time: 7.83853507042
find_duplicate time: 2.55058097839
total_duplicates count: 12348
max_duplicates count: 3
```

So how different is your scenario from this case, can it be done in similar way?

Comment: Probably it's a lot harder than that.  I'd guess he wants to eliminate things that are 'likely duplicate' and can't do just an exact match hash lookup.

Comment: @rrenaud, yes may be but 1) using any db etc wouldn't simplify it or speed it up 2) I think likely duplicate problem can be solved by pre-processing data and making it standard

Answer (score 0):

Unless this data has already been sanitised against the PAF (UK Post office Address file - every address in UK basically) then you will have addresses in there that are the same actual house, but spelt differently, wrong postcode, postcode in wrong field etc.  This will completely change your approach.

Check out if this is sanitised before you start.  The person giving it to you will either say "yes of course it has and I did it" or they will look blankly - in which case no.

If it is sanitised, great, probably an external agency is supplying your data and they probably can do this for you, but I expect oyu are being asked because its cheaper.  Get on.

If not, you have a range of problems and need to talk with your boss about what they want, how confidnet they want to be of matches etc.

In general the idea is to come up with a number of match algorithms per field, that output a confidence value that the two address under compare are the same.  Then a certain number of these values are weighted, and a total confidnece value has to be passed to consider the two addresses a match

But I am not clear this is your problem, but I do suggest you check what your boss exactly wants - this is not a clearly understood area between marketing and technical depats.

Comment: Assuming the OP is in a country where the postal system provides a "PAF", a reasonable first step would be to sanitise each record using the lowest house number; it's either quite OK, OK with changes to the street-etc component, unrecognisable/unfixable, street-etc OK but number is bad. Then maybe repeat with highest house number depending on outcome. Horrid thought: maybe the task is to *construct* a PAF for some smallish area! Another problem is that for utilities and emergency services, "delivery" address is not necessarily a postal address.